# How to use variable from looping as dictionary key in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

assumed that i have return a dictionary like this in my views or template_tags :

```
data = {key1:value1,key2:value2,......,keyn:valuen}
```

how can i generate something like this in my html template ?

```
value1
value2
value3
.
.
.
valuen
```

This is what i've got as far as i know :

```
 {% for i in data %}
 {% for j in data.i %}
 {{ j }} <br>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation page : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for this should work as you wish :

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ value }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you're right with the proviso that the data variable should be like this : data.items